getResource not retrieving images in Source Package
I am trying out a java with Ant slideshow in a video I found. I have made the output, and the window is appearing, but none of the images are being shown.
I suspect I have done something wrong pertaining to the getResource code i implentented. I expected that the getResource("/newsimages") would work and display all the images, but it won't.
package pbt2mainpage;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public final class MainPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MainPage() {
        initComponents();
        show(position);
    }
    
    int position = 0;
public String[] takeimage()
{
    File f = new File(getClass().getResource("/newsimages").getFile());
    String[] Images = f.list();
    return Images;
}

public void show(int index)
{
    String[] Images = takeimage();
    String img = Images[index];
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/newsimages/")+img);
    Image image = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(news.getHeight(), news.getWidth(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    news.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    
}
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        news = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        next = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        previous = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        background = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
        getContentPane().add(news, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(45, 55, 990, 360));

        next.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pbt2mainpage/next.png"))); // NOI18N
        next.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                nextMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(next, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(1040, 200, -1, -1));

        previous.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pbt2mainpage/previous.png"))); // NOI18N
        previous.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                previousMousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(previous, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(5, 200, -1, -1));

        background.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/pbt2mainpage/For CPG.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        getContentPane().add(background, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 1080, 450));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void nextMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        new Thread();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        int p = this.news.getX();
        
        if(p>-1)
        {
          Animacion.Animacion.mover_izquierda(900, 200, 1, 2, news);
        }
        position=position+1;
        if(position>=takeimage().length)
        {
            position=takeimage().length-1;
        }
        show(position);
    }                                 

    private void previousMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
       new Thread();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(300);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        int p=this.news.getX();
        
        if(p>-1)
        {
          Animacion.Animacion.mover_izquierda(900, 200, 1, 2, news);
        }
          position=position-1;
        if(position<0)
        {
            position=0;
        }
        show(position);
    }                                     

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new MainPage().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel background;
    private javax.swing.JLabel news;
    private javax.swing.JLabel next;
    private javax.swing.JLabel previous;
    // End of variables declaration                   


You can't list resources like that. The containers of resources are not necessarily directories. Read a text file containing a list of resources as a resource

new File(getClass().getResource("/newsimages").getFile()) ← Nope nope nope.  This has been covered many times on Stack Overflow.  The URL returned by getResource is not guaranteed to be a file URL.  And getFile() should never be used—despite its name, it does not return a valid file name.  You cannot list resources.

And you will need to change getClass().getResource("/newsimages/")+img to getClass().getResource("/newsimages/"+img), so your code passes a URL to ImageIcon, not a String, for a similar reason:  a resource is not guaranteed to be convertible a file name.  Also, you cannot sleep in event handlers;  it will hang your application.  Use javax.swing.Timer (not java.util.Timer!) instead.

File means File. This:
new File(getClass().getResource("/newsimages").getFile());

Does not work and cannot be made to work. Because those entries in your jar file are not files. They are jar entries.
This is how you do it, from your own code later in your source:
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/newsimages/")+img);

Though, you should be using MainPage.class.getResource instead (better style; does not break if you subclass, though that doesn't seem too relevant here).
Your code makes a file object in order to list its contents. This is not an operation you can do. The classloading system simply does not have a 'list' primitive.
Therefore, instead, you have a few choices:

Maintain a list of the files in there by hand, in your source code, or, in a text file with a known name. Then, you can load that text file (with MainPage.class.getResourceAsStream("/all-image-names.txt") for example), and use the contents of it to know which file names will be available.
Hack it, using various third party libraries. Note that these libraries fail in various circumstances. They work in the base case circumstance of having no modular or otherwise customized classloader infrastructure. Not recommended.
Set up your build so that it produces this text file automatically during the build. After all, during the build (compilation) phase, the tools certainly do have that file listing.


Thank you. These comments have helped me very much. just realized that using an outdated ide method on a new ide version may not have been the play.

Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsSTream("filename");

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
